# Closed form for integral $ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin (m \phi)}{(1 + r \cos \phi)^n} d\phi$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is there a closed form for $n>0$ integer, $m\neq 0$ integer, and $|r|<1$ real?

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565844/principal-value-of-the-singular-integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos-nt-cos-t-co/565862#565862).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: that technique does not apply at least when $n$ is odd; in that case, one cannot just simply extend the integral over the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin m\phi}{(1+r\cos\phi)^n}d\phi$

$=\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin\phi~U_{m-1}(\cos\phi)}{(1+r\cos\phi)^n}d\phi$ (according to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html)

$=-\int_0^\pi\dfrac{U_{m-1}(\cos\phi)}{(1+r\cos\phi)^n}d(\cos\phi)$

$=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{U_{m-1}(x)}{(1+rx)^n}dx$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{{\cal I}_{mn}\pars{r} \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi}
     {\sin\pars{m\phi} \over \bracks{1 + r\cos\pars{\phi}}^{n}}\,\dd\phi\,,\qquad
      \mbox{Notice that}\ {\cal I}_{mn}\pars{r} = -{\cal I}_{-m,n}\pars{r}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}_{mn}\pars{r} &=
> \left.{-\cos\pars{m\phi}/m
>        \over
>        \bracks{1 +r\cos\pars{\phi}}^{n}}\right\vert_{0}^{\pi}
> -
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{-\,{\cos\pars{m\phi} \over m}}\braces{%
> -n\,{-r\sin\pars{\phi} \over \bracks{1 + r\cos\pars{\phi}}^{n + 1}}}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over m}\bracks{%
> {\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over \pars{1 - r}^{n}}
> +
> {1 \over \pars{1 + r}^{n}}}
> +
> {nr \over m}\int_{0}^{\pi}
> {\cos\pars{m\phi}\sin\pars{\phi}
>  \over
>  \bracks{1 + r\cos\pars{\phi}}^{n + 1}}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over m}\bracks{%
> {\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over \pars{1 - r}^{n}}
> +
> {1 \over \pars{1 + r}^{n}}}
> +
> {nr \over m}\int_{0}^{\pi}
> {\braces{\sin\pars{\bracks{m + 1}\phi} - \sin\pars{\bracks{m - 1}\phi}}/2
>  \over
>  \bracks{1 + r\cos\pars{\phi}}^{n + 1}}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over m}\bracks{%
> {\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over \pars{1 - r}^{n}}
> +
> {1 \over \pars{1 + r}^{n}}}
> +
> {nr \over 2m}\bracks{{\cal I}_{m + 1,n + 1}\pars{r} - {\cal I}_{m - 1,n + 1}\pars{r}}
> \end{align}

$$
{\cal I}_{m + 1,n + 1}\pars{r}
=
-\,{2 \over nr}\bracks{%
{\pars{-1}^{m + 1} \over \pars{1 - r}^{n}} + {1 \over \pars{1 + r}^{n}}}
+
{2m \over nr}\,{\cal I}_{mn}\pars{r} + {\cal I}_{m - 1,n + 1}\pars{r}\,,\qquad
m \geq 1
$$
with
$$
{\cal I}_{0n}\pars{r} = 0 \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
{\cal I}_{1n}\pars{r}
=
{\pars{1 - r}^{-\pars{n - 1}} - \pars{1 + r}^{-\pars{n - 1}} \over r\pars{n - 1}}\,,
\quad {\cal I}_{-m,n}\pars{r} = -{\cal I}_{mn}\pars{r} 
$$

Comment: Interesting recursion, but $I_{11}$ needs to be corrected.

Comment: Can a similar technique work for non-integer $m$? I wonder if you can solve this integral with an appropriate limit for $m\rightarrow 0^+$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582397/closed-form-for-integral-int-0-pi-1-r-cos-phi-n-phi-d-phi

Comment: @bkocsis, you may have already computed this, but for reference: for $r = 0$, $I_{11} = \int_0^\pi \sin \phi \, d\phi = 2$. For $|r| < 1$ and $r \not= 0$, $u$-substitution (with $u = 1 + r \cos \phi$) yields $I_{11} = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin \phi}{1 + r \cos \phi} \, d\phi = \int_{1+r}^{1-r} \frac{1}{u} \, \frac{du}{-r} = \frac{\ln(1+r) - \ln(1-r)}{r}$.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks. The last one ( the logarithmic one ) is found from the limit $\large n \to 1$ of my result with L'Hopital Rule. Thanks for your clear help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \sin(m x) \cos^k(x)dx = I(m,k)$. We have
$$I = \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin(m x)dx}{(1+r \cos(x))^n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-r)^k \dbinom{n+k-1}k\int_0^{\pi} \sin(mx) \cos^k(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-r)^k \dbinom{n+k-1}k I(m,k)$$

[Note that we also have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition)

$$I(m,k) = \int_0^{\pi}\sin(mx) \cos^k(x) dx = \int_0^{\pi}U_{m-1}(\cos(x)) \sin(x) \cos^k(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 t^k U_{m-1}(t)dt$$
where $U_{m-1}$ is the $(m-1)^{th}$ Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Hence, $I(m,k)$ is the $k^{th}$ moment of the $(m-1)^{th}$ Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.

Comment: Felix Martin's solution shows that this simplifies to a finite sum. Can you generate an explicit solution with Chebysev polynomials?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but shouldn't this be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-r)^k\binom{k+n-1}{k}\int_0^\pi\sin(mx)\cos^k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, It should be $\dbinom{n+k}k$. Fixed.

Comment: $\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ [Third formula here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem), or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_negative_integers).

Comment: @robjohn Oh yes. Thanks.

Comment: Heh. I just came across [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/217645) which we both answered.

Comment: @robjohn Ha. Yes :-)