# $\int_{0}^{\pi} \exp\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)\cos\left(\sin\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t=\pi$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Does anyone have a proof of the above integral? I have one proof, but I wanted to see other proofs.

Comment: How would someone know whether they are writing another proof?

Comment: Before we waste time typing up an alternate proof, show us the one we have to avoid duplication.

Comment: Try this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565844/principal-value-of-the-singular-integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos-nt-cos-t-co/565862#565862).

Comment: You should show your work as said in the above comments.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

By some simple change of variables we get
$$\int_0^\pi e^{\cos t}\cos\sin tdt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos \theta}\cos \sin\theta d\theta=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}}d\theta\right) = \pi\cdot\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{e^z}{z}dz\right),$$
where $C$ is the unit circle. Now use Cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$\cos(\sin(t)) = \text{Real}(e^{i \sin(t)})$. Hence, the integral we want is
$$I = \text{Real}\left(\int_0^{\pi} e^{e^{it}}dt \right)$$
We have
$$e^{e^{it}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ikt}}{k!}$$
Hence,
$$I = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{I_k}{k!}$$
where $I_k = \text{Real}\left(\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} e^{ikt}dt \right) = \pi \delta_k$. Hence, we are done.

**Updated to answer TCL's claim**:

I do not understand TCL's claim "I was hoping to see a proof without complex analysis, but that seems to be not possible." My proof does not rely on complex analysis at all. Writing $\cos(t)$ as Real($e^{it}$) is just a notational convenience. All we are making use of is the following identity:
$$\exp(\cos(t)) \cos(\sin(t)) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(kt)}{k!}$$

Comment: You are right. At first I didn't understand your $\delta_k$ notation, so I didn't read your post thoroughly. Now I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integrand is even, this is half of the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$ That, in turn is an integral over the unit circle of a meromorphic function, and thus can be done using Cauchy's integral formula. Computing the residue is a bit tedious. But then, maybe it's the same as your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Mean Value Property to the function $e^z$ at 0, we get for any $r>0$,  $$1=e^0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(re^{it})\,dt$$
Using the fact that the integrand is $2\pi$ periodic and that $\exp(r\cos t)\sin(r\sin(t))$ is odd and $\exp(r\cos t)\cos(r\sin(t))$ is even, we find $$1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \exp(r\cos t)\cos(r\sin t)\,dt.$$
I was hoping to see a proof without complex analysis, but that seems to be not possible.

Comment: I do not understand your claim "I was hoping to see a proof without complex analysis, but that seems to be not possible." My proof does not rely on complex analysis at all. Writing $\cos(t)$ as $\text{Real}(e^{it})$ is just a notational convenience.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
     =
     \int_{-\pi}^{0}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
     =
     -\int_{\pi}^{0}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t}$
$\ds{=\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t}$

> Then,
> \begin{align}
> &\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t} 
> =\half\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{\cos\pars{t}}\cos\pars{\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
> =\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{\expo{\ic t}}\,\dd t 
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\expo{z}\,\pars{-\ic\,{\dd z \over z}}
> =\half\,\Re\lim_{z \to 0}\pars{2\pi\ic\,z\,{-\ic\expo{z} \over z}}
> =\color{#0000ff}{\Large\pi} 
> \end{align}