# Improper integral with trig functions

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

A colleague of mine came across this equation on an old exam: $$
 \int_0^{\pi}{\cos n\theta\over\cos\theta-\cos\phi}\,d\theta={\pi\sin n\phi\over\sin\phi}
 $$ It said on the exam that students were allowed to assume this result.

My colleague (and I) would be much obliged if someone could present a reference to, or a proof of (or a refutation of), this formula. I suppose one is to assume $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: I'd ask Wadim, Gerry. He may know off the top of his head, if not someone else at carma.

Comment: @Will, good idea. But first I'll see whether anything turns up here. 2,000 heads are better than one.

Comment: Everyone, note this si a Cauchy Principal Value in any case, around $\theta = \phi,$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: Take a look at: http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R(x,cos)#2.3 for a similar problem (albeit with a solution).

Comment: Is $\large n$ an integer ?.

Comment: @Felix, there was no mention on the exam paper, but (as I wrote in the question) I suppose one is to assume $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: The left side is even in $\large n$ while the right side is odd. Maybe, it means it was calculated for positive $\large n$. Thanks.

Comment: Could not find anything much like it in Wikipedia's long list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions

Comment: In @Argon link, there is a [hint](http://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R(x,cos)&action=edit&section=12) . They got the same result with $\cos\left(n\theta\right) - \cos\left(n\phi\right)$ ( in the numerator ) instead of $\cos\left(n\theta\right)$ alone.

Comment: Try comlex variable techniques.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565844/principal-value-of-the-singular-integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos-nt-cos-t-co) is exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Mhenni, thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Gerry : you are welcome.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Hayatsu, I've tried talking sense to you, but all you did was delete a bunch of your posts – after complaining that others had deleted one of your posts. This is **not** the place to carry on our "discussions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to attack this problem here because a) this was never closed as a duplicate, and b) the link given in the comments above is to an alleged duplicate in which the accepted answer is useless enough to be not even wrong.  I will demonstrate.

Consider the following contour integral:

$$ \oint_C \frac{dz}{z^n} \frac{z^{2 n}+1}{z^2-2 z \cos{\phi}+1} $$

where $C$ is the following contour:

[image]

$C$ is the positively-oriented unit circle deformed at $z=e^{\pm i \phi}$ by semicircles of radii $\epsilon$ into the unit circle.  Thus, the only pole of the integrand is at $z=0$.

The contour integral is thus equal to

$$i \int_{-\pi}^{-\phi-\epsilon} d\theta \frac{\cos{n \theta}}{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\phi}} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 dt \, e^{i t} \frac{(e^{-i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^n + (e^{-i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^{-n}}{(e^{-i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^2-2 \cos{\phi} (e^{-i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})+1} \\ +i \int_{-\phi+\epsilon}^{\phi-\epsilon} d\theta \frac{\cos{n \theta}}{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\phi}} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 dt \, e^{i t} \frac{(e^{i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^n + (e^{i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^{-n}}{(e^{i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})^2-2 \cos{\phi} (e^{i \phi}+\epsilon e^{i t})+1}\\ +i \int_{\phi+\epsilon}^{\pi} d\theta \frac{\cos{n \theta}}{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\phi}}$$

We now take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.  In this limit, the second integral and the fourth integrals cancel each other out because they approach the value

$$\frac{\pi \cos{n \phi}}{\sin{\phi}} - \frac{\pi \cos{n \phi}}{\sin{\phi}} $$

The contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the pole $z=0$. Thus, we have

$$i PV \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \frac{\cos{n \theta}}{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\phi}} = \frac{i 2 \pi}{(n-1)!} \left [ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \frac{z^{2 n}+1}{z^2-2 z \cos{\phi}+1} \right ]_{z=0} $$

As for the term in the brackets, we note that the $(n-1)$th derivative of a product of two functions is simply a binomial-type expression:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}[f(z) g(z)]}{dz^{n-1}}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{d^k f(z)}{dz^k} \frac{d^{n-1-k} g(z)}{dz^{n-1-k}} $$

where $f(z) = z^{2 n}+1$ and $g(z)=(z^2-2 \cos{\phi}+1)^{-1} $.  Note that, because we are evaluating this derivative at $z=0$, all derivative terms involving $f(z)$ are zero.  Since $f(0)=1$, our residue is merely

$$\frac1{(n-1)!}  \left [ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \frac{1}{z^2-2 z \cos{\phi}+1} \right ]_{z=0} $$

At this point I invoke the well known [generating function for the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition) is

$$\frac1{z^2-2 x z+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} U_k(x) z^k $$

where

$$U_k(\cos{\phi}) = \frac{\sin{(k+1) \phi}}{\sin{\phi}} $$

Thus, we may finally say that

$$PV \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \frac{\cos{n \theta}}{\cos{\theta}-\cos{\phi}} = 2 \pi \frac{\sin{n \phi}}{\sin{\phi}}$$

and the stated result follows.

I may now explain my "not even wrong" comment above.  If one follows the hint given in the accepted answer in the above-linked-to question, one may arrive at this correct answer.  However, that hint is terrible advice based on a fundamental misunderstanding of contour integration techniques.  Integrals of functions having poles on the contour are undefined unless defined in a Cauchy principal value sense, as done above.  (Note here that by "PV", I mean avoiding *both* poles.)  It just so happened that the contributions of the deformed pieces of the contour cancel; most times, that will certainly not be the case.  That's why the hint is not even wrong: because, by taking it, one stumbles upon the correct result without appreciating why.

Comment: Everywhere you have $z^2-2\cos\phi+1$, you mean to have $z^2-2z\cos\phi+1$, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: of course, I will correct as soon as I can.